# R: Bootstrap Mean Squared Error to test predictive performance of three models

Tags: r, bootstrap, mse

I have an investigator that wants to test predictive performance of three models. The three models predict hospital stay.

Formula A is a formula:  (x1/100 + x2*2)/x3 = expected length of hospital stay where x1,x2,x3 are all clinical risk factors.
Formula B is the formula: x4 = expected length of hospital stay
Formula B is a automated formula that the institution creates. I do not have the formula but I am given what the expected length of hospital stay is.

I am given a data set (800 observations) that has all of the predictors listed above (x1,x2,x3,x4, actual length of stay and the hospital's expected length of stay.

My colleague suggested that I use bootstrapping to calculate the mean-squared error and then use the 95% percentile confidence interval.

However, the distribution of the bootstrapped samples is not-normal, very skewed to the right

[image: Photo of bootstrapped distribution]

My questions are:

1. Do you think this is a good method to test the performance of the formulas?
2. If so, is it okay to report the 95% confidence interval given the distribution of the bootstrapped estimates are skewed?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think it's a reasonable method, but I would want to check that the formulae hadn't been derived with the exact same data set that you have. Otherwise, they could've manually "overfitted" the formulae to that data set and bootstrapping wouldn't solve this issue.
2. Yes, that's okay. Using Normal CIs would be problematic with skewed data, but percentile-based CIs should work fine. That said, remember that bootstrapping only works well if you can assume that your 800 observations are representative of the wider population.